# Index on fields with a function

Tags: mysql, index, functions

I have a log table. It logs visitor data (time of visit, browser, window size ...).

I want to create reports. I use a query like this (MySQL):

```
SELECT
COUNT(*) as raw_views ...
FROM logs
WHERE timestamp >= CURDATE()
GROUP BY HOUR(timestamp)
```

The problem is `HOUR(timestamp)`. I am using a function on this field, so the index won't work. But the table is huge. Index are very important. But how else can I create hourly (or daily, yearly, monthly) reports?

I think I have this problem: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sargable

But there must be a way somehow, or how else are other people doing it?

Comment: Add `year`, `month`, `date`, `hour` columns and index on them. Or use MariaDB and index `PERSISTENT` computed columns.

Comment: I am handling multiple timezones. It would get messy if I just add for example a `hour` column. I really don't want to change to another database ... However I am going to do some research on MariaDB and `PERSISTENT` index. But if I do this am I going to be able to use index like that? Any drawbacks?

Comment: No, it won't get messy. Not with the query you provided. If your requirements are different, edit the question. MariaDB can be installed as a replacement of MySQL. You'll probably have no issues at all (but of course you need to test !)

Comment: If I add a `hour` column (store the hours in UTC) and do  `GROUP BY hour` MySQL or my script can't know what hour this would be in the timezone of the user who is requesting the report. However from a `timestamp` column you can actually find out what hour it would be according to users timezone. Please correct me if I am mistaken.

Comment: The application that will show the results of the query to the user can do that, can't it? It knows the timezone of the user and can do the conversion.

Comment: Sorry, I might be to stupid to see it... but no, it can't. For example the user request today's logs. For example in one column the value of `hour` is `4`. This value is stored in UTC. The timestamp value is `2014-08-01 04:50:36`. Let's say the user is in a country with +15 min offset. Ok, the script needs to add +15min to the `hour`. `4 + 0.15 = 4.15`. So till the hour value is `4`. But it should be `5` because: `04:50:36 + 00:15:00 = 05:05:36`